# How to split a python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylance

First, I'm sorry for these stupid questions.
I'm try to looking for how to split my python program in different part. I have a file .py and in this file there is all my program. I would like to split this in 3 different file: Main, constant and functions.
(Does these files need a particular extension?)
I organized the functions file like this:

```
import .....

def function0:
....

def function1:
....

etc.
```

Is that a wrong method? When I try to import this file `.py` in the main file, IDE gives me a yellow line and `Import "functions" could not be resolved` but everything works fine.

[image]

Does it make sense to do it this way?

All these files are located in the same folder.

Comment: seems like you are making some basic syntax error. Check your syntax

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/236

Comment: The warnings are only in VS Code. You need to set up [work spaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces).

Comment: Thanks, now i will try to set up a workspaces

Comment: I tried to create a workspace and I solved the problem. Thank you Justin. I also thank those who tried to help me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, when you are importing the file, the files are in the same folder, and you are only using `import functionfile`, NOT `import functionfile.py`

<s>**EDIT:** Are you sure you are using a lowercase "i" in import? I notice you've referred to it as "Import" twice now</s>

**EDIT 2** Now I'm thinking it's just Visual Studio Code not recognizing the valid import. This has happened to me before, and restarting VSCode always seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, i'm sure, I'm using "Import functionfile". Files are located in the same folder.

Comment: make sure you are doing "import", not "Import". Sorry if I shouldn't have added a comment as well as the edit, I'm new to contributing here

Comment: Thanks, I'm using "import". Visual Studio Code

Comment: OK, this may be a stupid question, but have you actually tried running the code, or just going by what VSCode is telling you? Sometimes, it seems like VSCode can miss imports and throw false errors.

Comment: The Code works fine but VScode cannot predict what I am trying to use

Comment: ok, now i try to uninstall and reinstall VScode, thanks

Comment: Maybe don't jump to that quite yet. Have you just tried exiting out of VSCode completely (closing the program) and then opening it back up?

Comment: I tried to create a workspace and I solved the problem. Thanks a lot anyway.